# Inserting empty values into python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that I ultimately want to insert into a mysql database. I'm parsing data from something called "entries" which goes like (the # symbolize numbers):

```
entries = [ "['data'] runtime: ###, scan: ###", 
            "['data'] ctime: ###, scan: ###", 
            "['data'] runtime: ###", ... ]
```

Each thing in the "" is a separate entry. Now I use regex to extract the runtimes, ctimes, and scans associated with each entry like so:

```
import re
terms = (["runtime", "runtime\s?:\s?(\d+)"],
         ["ctime", "ctime\s?:\s?(\d+)"],
         ["scan", "scan\s?:\s?(\d+)"])
d = {}
for i in range(len(terms)):
    def getTerm(term, entries):
        pattern = re.compile(term)
        output = pattern.findall(str(entries))
        return output
    d[terms[i][0]] = getTerm(terms[i][1], entries)
```

This works -- however, as you can see, not all of the entries have a runtime, ctime, and scan. If a value doesn't appear in an entry, I want it to be entered into my dictionary as [] or NULL (or None), because in the future if I look at a specific # element of each key in my dictionary, I want all that data to be associated with one specific entry. I want my dictionary to then look like this:

```
d = {'ctime': [None, '###', None], 'runtime': ['###', None, '###'], 'scan': ['###', '###', None]}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `entries` is a list of strings that may or may not contain the keywords and order is important then we'll need to iterate over the entries:

First option:

```
import re

entries = [ "['data'] runtime: ###, scan: ###",
            "['data'] ctime: ###, scan: ###",
            "['data'] runtime: ###" ]

allterms = (["runtime", "runtime\s?:\s?([a-zA-Z0-9_#]*)"],
            ["ctime", "ctime\s?:\s?([a-zA-Z0-9_#]*)"],
            ["scan", "scan\s?:\s?([a-zA-Z0-9_#]*)"])
terms = [allterms[i][0] for i in range(len(allterms))]
patterns = [allterms[i][1] for i in range(len(allterms))]

def get_terms(entry):
    for i in range(len(terms)):
        term = re.search(patterns[i], entry)
        term = term.groups()[0] if term else None
        d[terms[i]] += [term]
        pass

d = {t: [] for t in allterms}
for entry in entries:
     get_terms(entry)
```

Second option with async:

```
# pip install futures  # if using Python 2 
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

d = {t: [] for t in allterms}
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for entry in entries:
        get_terms(entry)
```

Edit: Solution developed in chat collab with @Wynne :)

Comment: I like it, that's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, although I tried the second example (just adding 'or None' to the return line inside my loop) and it only adds None if it can't find any matches in all the entries, but it isn't doing it entry-by-entry. Any idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Hmmm, what does the entire `entries` string look like? As is above, the expected result is: `{'ctime': None, 'runtime': None, 'scan': None}`

Comment: The format of entries is what I wrote as an example in my question which is actually a list, and I want the dictionary to produce something like this: {'ctime': [None, '###', None], 'runtime': ['###', None, '###'], 'scan': ['###', '###', None]} as it looks for the regex matches entry-to-entry.

Comment: The regex as is will match numbers. Are you looking for the hashtags like `###` or actual numbers?

Comment: I think we will need to replace the `findall` method if we are to capture non-matches as well as matches.

Comment: The matches are either actual numbers or strings. Yes, the idea is that I want to capture non-matches as well so that the dictionary comes out in the form I'd like.

Comment: It looks like it should be a list like `entries = [ "['data'] runtime: ###, scan: ###", "['data'] runtime: ###, scan: ###", .. ]` Updating my answer

Comment: @Brennan unfortunately my actual dictionary is far too large to do this sort of code. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I made it asynchronous, how about now?

Comment: Is this module available on Python 2.7? I'm getting an ImportError.

Comment: Updated the answer with regex methods. For option 2, Try `pip install futures`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153182/discussion-between-wynne-t-and-brennan).

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall()` return an empty list (`[]`) when no match is found, so you don't need an empty fallback. If you want to have `None` when no term is found, as Brennan said, user `findall(string) or None`.

Consider using list comprehension to loop over all your entries, and dict comprehension to apply your regex patterns over the same entry and save the result in a dict.

```
import re
terms = (["runtime", re.compile("runtime\s?:\s?(\d+)")],
         ["ctime", re.compile("ctime\s?:\s?(\d+)")],
         ["scan", re.compile("scan\s?:\s?(\d+)")])
results = [{property: pattern.findall(entry) for property, pattern in terms} for entry in entries]
```

now you have something like:

```
[{"runtime": None, "scan": ###, "ctime": ###}, {"runtime": ###, "scan": ###, "ctime": ###}, {"runtime": ###, "scan": None, "ctime": None}, ...]
```

The above code is equivalent (but more performant) to:

```
results = []
for entry in entries:
    entry_dict = {}
    for term, regex_pattern in terms:
        entry_dict[term] = regex_pattern.findall(entry) or None
    results.append(entry_dict)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without creating multiple dictionaries? I'd like to still have only one dictionary and have the data displayed in the dict as what I wrote in my new edit to my question.

Comment: I went ahead and tried your code anyway to see if it would work but it didn't; I'm dealing with the same issue as in the beginning

Comment: I tought you wanted a pivotted output, to do what you want yo have to invert the list and the dict comprehension: `{propery: [pattern.findall(entry) or None for entry in entries] for property, pattern in terms}`